# How to make the command-line / interpreter pane/window bigger in pudb?

Tags: python, pudb

Is there any way to resize the command-line / interpreter window/pane in pudb, just like the size of the side pane can be adjusted?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Put the focus in the command-line / interpreter pane (using Ctrl-x).
2. Use the right-arrow key to put the focus on the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button. (the background changes color to indicate it is selected)
3. Now use any of the following commands:

- `_` (underscore; makes that pane the smallest size possible)
- `=` (equals; makes that pane the largest size possible)
- `+` (plus; increases the size of that pane with each press)
- `-` (minus; decreases the size of that pane with each press)

Comment: In step 2, if I put the focus on the <clear> button, then step 3 works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @auro!  Angle brackets (<>'s) around Clear was causing it not to be displayed.  I have now fixed it removing the brackets.

Comment: Do you know of a way to make the expanded size the default size? I would like it to always start with a bigger size